# Moving to SQL Server CE 4 from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have a website where I have an SQL Server database, but I want to get rid of SQL Server and move into a more compact/modular system. SQL Server CE 4 suits my needs, but I have a problem. I've searched for hours and couldn't find a tool to move my database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server CE 4.

I try to script my database schema+data from SSMS and try to query it into my SQL Server CE file, but I get tons of different errors. I've tried the Import/Export database wizard but I couldn't find a way to set the destination as a SQL Server CE database. I've found a few programs, but none of them worked (e.g. http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html errors right after starting the transfer).

I've looked at LOTS of StackOverflow questions about these but none of them helped me. I lastly tried to move the schema and data separately but ended up getting errors about identity columns while inserting.

How can I move my SQL Server database (2012 on my machine, but I have access to 2008 backup files (`.BAK`) of the databases too from GoDaddy) to a SQL Server CE 4 file? Again, getting the SQL Server data is easy part, but SQL Server CE complains almost about everything while trying to script my schema/data in.

Comment: Have you looked at [Erik EJ's Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/) web site? He has tons of tips, articles, how-to's, and tools, too.

Comment: More details here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html

Comment: oh, I've already installed it (and its a great tool) but i didn't know that it can script sql server databases for sql ce.